# Postgresql - Why is my function returning only 1 row and 1 column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I'm using northwind database and I'm trying to make a stored procedure that list the name and order with category id as the input parameter. Here is my function.

```
 create or replace function orders(categoryid smallint) 
            returns table 
                         (productname varchar, 
                          unitsonorder smallint) as  $$ 
  begin return query 
                        select productname,unitsonorder 
                                 from products where 
                         unitsonorder >=1 and categoryid = $1;
   end $$ language plpgsql;
```

I executed this function "select orders(1);" and it returned this result

Result:
 [image]

The result that I'm after is:

[image]

Somehow the query inside my function is not returning all the rows and colum and I'm stuck here for hours.

Comment: Have you tried:  `select * from orders(1)`?

Comment: Yes and it is still returning the same result.

Comment: If you run the same query outside the function you get a different result?

Comment: yes just like the second image.